# Grid layout columns and rows not working

Tags: java, swing, grid-layout

Basically I am trying to attach two panels onto my frame,
my frame uses `BorderLayout` and the two panels will be placed North and south.
I am done with the top panel but for the bottom one I cannot get it right.
I used `GridLayout` for the bottom one and it's supposed to look like this.

> http://i47.tinypic.com/wa0lsz.png

So here is the code for the gridlayout

```
public class WeaponComp extends JPanel{


protected JPanel first = new JPanel();

public WeaponComp(){

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,550));
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    JLabel ntg = new JLabel("");
    JLabel oldweap = new JLabel("OLD WEAPON");
            JLabel newweap = new JLabel("NEW WEAPON");

    JLabel onetwohand = new JLabel ("1H / 2H");
    JLabel offhand = new JLabel ("Off Hand");
    JLabel dps = new JLabel ("DPS :");
    JLabel str = new JLabel ("Str :");
    JLabel dex = new JLabel ("Dex :");
    JLabel vit = new JLabel ("Vit :");
    JLabel intel = new JLabel ("Int :");
    JLabel manareg = new JLabel ("Mana Regen :");
    JLabel aspd = new JLabel ("Attack Speed:");
    JLabel critch = new JLabel ("Crit chance:");
    JLabel critdmg = new JLabel ("Crit damage:");

    JTextField dpstf = new JTextField(12);
    JTextField strtf = new JTextField(5);
    JTextField dextf = new JTextField(5);
    JTextField vittf = new JTextField(5);
    JTextField inteltf = new JTextField(5);
    JTextField manaregtf = new JTextField(3);
    JTextField aspdtf = new JTextField(3);
    JTextField critchtf = new JTextField(3);
    JTextField critdmgtf = new JTextField(3);
    JTextField offdpstf = new JTextField(12);
    JTextField offstrtf = new JTextField(5);
    JTextField offdextf = new JTextField(5);
    JTextField offvittf = new JTextField(5);
    JTextField offinteltf = new JTextField(5);
    JTextField offmanaregtf = new JTextField(3);
    JTextField offaspdtf = new JTextField(3);
    JTextField offcritchtf = new JTextField(3);
    JTextField offcritdmgtf = new JTextField(3);

    first.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,4));
    first.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750,150));

    first.add(oldweap); first.add(ntg); first.add(newweap); first.add(ntg);
    first.add(onetwohand); first.add(ntg); first.add(offhand); first.add(ntg);
    first.add(dps); first.add(dpstf); first.add(dps); first.add(offdpstf);


    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 0; c.gridy = 0;
    add (first,c); 

}
}
```

Here is the current result of my program

> http://i50.tinypic.com/107p9uu.png

Thank you in advance for your time and answers

PS : and in case you're wondering, yes, it has something to do with diablo 3
But I am not that ambitious, this is for learning purpose and won't have many functionality.

Answer (score 3):

GridLayout is a poor choice, because all cells automatically have the same size. I suggest using MigLayout instead: http://miglayout.com

The layout code would look like this:

```
first.setLayout(new MigLayout("wrap 2, fill"));
first.add(oldweap);
first.add(newweap);
first.add(onetwohand);
first.add(offhand);
first.add(dps);
first.add(dpstf);
first.add(dps);
first.add(offdpstf);
```

Comment: +1, MigLayout is amost always a good option for many JComponents in 1 JPanel.

Comment: Thanks Emmanual, I will look at the miglayout
but this does not solve my curiosity, I thought grid is perfectly fine with 3 rows and 4 columns in this particular case but having their order messed is strange and this has made me really curious.
I am still looking for a solution based on gridlayout, but I will still check out the mig, thank you once again.

Comment: GridLayout will really look horrible, the textfields will have a non standard height and the text baselines will not be aligned. If you really want to see how it looks, you have to duplicate the 'ntg' blank element, because an object can only be added once to a container.

Comment: I think that's the answer I'm looking for, ntg can be used only once
Thank you so much for this

Answer (score 3):

You might use [`GroupLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/GroupLayout.html)<sup>1</sup> or a [nested layout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556)<sup>2</sup> for the bottom panels.

1. See [How to Use GroupLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html) for details.  E.G. 
   [image]
2. E.G.
   [image]